# Why is it not good to set cell attributes in cellForItemAt?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview

In a meeting with other iOS developers, I overheard criticism with setting view attributes in cellForItemAt (such as background color, images, labels, etc) because it was "the wrong way to do it".

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let headerCell = calendarCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.backgroundColor = .red
    cell.titleLabel = "This is my text"
    return cell
}
```

I know the right way to set the view attributes is to do it in the custom cell file, but Im not sure what the difference is between doing it here versus the custom cell file. If the code behaves the same, what is the difference and why is this the "wrong way to do it"? Is it because this conflicts with MVC pattern?

Comment: Whoever told you that is stupid. It's not good to create view's in cell for row at indexpath (hence why you dequeue a cell instead of recreating one every time).. but setting attributes is what it's for.. You configure your cell there (set colours, change text, etc..)

Comment: I don't see any issue, especially not when modifications settings are limited in number. You don't always want to write that in another file. What can be wrong is that you expose all your properties. That's what I think can be argued. But in my experience it's often a time sensitive issue to expose them (and then money). For just setting a label.text valuel, I'd write it there. Now, this code is called each time a cell is reused, some info like color if it's always the same could be done once only per cell in awakeFromNib or init.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is no different than any other decision you make when you write object-oriented code. Code should be put where it belongs.

You have a custom cell. That custom cell should know more about itself than any view controller that uses it. The custom cell should be the primary class that creates and sets up its own subviews based on data and state information the view controller (really the table view's data source) provides to the cell.

It's very common for people to fill `cellForRow` with way too much cell setup code. This is a bad practice. The cell is a view. A view is responsible for setting itself up as needed. The data source (the controller) should only give the cell data and state and then the cell should configure itself accordingly.

Having said that, the custom cell view may also be somewhat generic and different controllers may wish the cell to appear differently. A good simple example is the code in the question. This controller wants the cell to have a red background. But another controller may use the same cell class but want a blue background. For simple cases like this, the controller (`cellForRowAt`) is a good place to set the cell's color.

In simple cases, put a couple of lines in `cellForRowAt` to set the color and title.

In more complicated cases where the cell shows images, multiple text values, and has a more complicated layout, then `cellForRowAt` should pass data to the cell and the cell should do all of the complicated layout. This moves the knowledge of the cell's structure to the cell where it belongs.

Think about other view class provided by the iOS SDK where you do not directly set subview properties. Examples include `UIAlertController/UIAlertAction`, `UITextField`, and many others. You set properties on these views and the view updates itself accordingly. Treat table view cells in a similar fashion.